# Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable error

Tags: swift, swiftui, getter-setter, getter, computed-properties

I'm trying to reuse an older piece of Swift code, but getting an error 'Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable error'. Xcode wanted to add 'mutating' before the func, and offered to do so through a 'fix'. So the error is gone there but still remains at the 'Text' statements.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

     typealias PointTuple = (day: Double, mW: Double)
    let points: [PointTuple] = [(0.0, 31.98), (1.0, 31.89), (2.0, 31.77), (4.0, 31.58), (6.0, 31.46)]

    lazy var meanDays = points.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.0 } / Double(points.count)
    lazy var meanMW   = points.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.1 } / Double(points.count)

    lazy var a = points.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.day - meanDays) * ($1.mW - meanMW) }
    lazy var b = points.reduce(0) { $0 + pow($1.day - meanDays, 2) }

    lazy var m = a / b
    lazy var c = meanMW - m * meanDays        
    lazy var x : Double = bG(day: 3.0)
    lazy var y : Double = bG(day: 5.0)
    lazy var z : Double = bG(day: 7.0)

    mutating func bG(day: Double) -> Double {
        return m * day + c
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(x)")
            Text("\(y)")
            Text("\(z)")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: A workaround solution I found to this problem is to use computed properties instead of lazy vars. I don't understand why I can't use lazy vars however, neither do I understand the proposed solution

Comment: @charel-f I wrote a new answer. Please take a look

Comment: Thanks, your new answer is very concise and easy to understand

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because when you call `x` inside the struct, it's not clear whether the `contentView` itself is mutable or not. A value type gets mutable  **only when** it is defined as a `var`.

So it would help if you wrapped it with an immutable value before using it inside a builder function inside the struct.

like this:

```
func xValue() -> Double {
    var mutatableSelf = self
    return mutatableSelf.x
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(xValue())")
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: `Lazy` property's value will be associated on the first call and this mutates the object. So they are considered as `mutating`

Answer (score 24):

## A getter cannot mutate

This is mainly a design Swift is enforcing with its getters. The principle is:

The getters should not mutate the object. Because developers may not be expecting that. They should only expect a change when you're using the *setter* or calling a *mutating* function. A getter is neither of them.

The following example works as expected:

```
struct Device {
    var isOn = true
}

let a = Device()
let b = a

print(a.isOn)
```

When we print, we *get* the value of `a.isOn`. Both a,b are identical.

Yet in the following example, the getter will have a side-effect. It won't even compile. But let's just assume that it did and see what happens.

```
struct Device2 {
    
    var x = 3
    var isOn: Bool {
        x = 5
        return true
    }
}

let a = Device2()
let b = a

print(a.isOn)
```

When we print, we *get* the value of `a.isOn`. However this time the a,b are no longer identical. `a.x` will now be 5, because a copy-on-write would have happened, while `b.x` would still be 3.

Swift has an architecture that doesn't allow "getters to mutate an object".

## Exceptions

The Swift architecture has two exceptions to this rule:

- use `lazy`
- use `@State` or some other property wrapper managed by SwiftUI that can be written to and manages state.

### Lazy is mutating:

```
struct Device2 {
    lazy var x : Double = 3.0

    func log() {
        print(x)
    } 
}
```

Even thought `print(x)` will mutate `x` upon *getting* the value of `x`, it's fine because `x` is a `lazy` property.

You might be wondering what's different between `lazy var x = 5` and `var x = 5` and the answer is that the latter has the value of `x` set upon initialization of the struct...

### SwiftUI - special case

Because the `body` variable is a computed property, you can't mutate/set variables. There's a way around that though.

Mark the variable with a `@State` property wrapper.

Example. The following code won't compile:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var currentDate = Date()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(currentDate)")
            .onReceive(timer) { input in
                currentDate = input // ERROR: Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
        }
    }
}
```

Yet the following will compile, just because it has `@State`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentDate = Date()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(currentDate)")
            .onReceive(timer) { input in
                currentDate = input
        }
    }
}
```

For more on that see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fix-cannot-assign-to-property-self-is-immutable)

Comment: This helped me realize that a lazy property mutates the object on the first invocation and so will always be considered as `mutating`. It's unfortunate but it at least makes sense now.

Comment: @SebastienMartin lol. I generated the error without using lazy properties. Then I noticed your comment and learned that lazy properties are implicitly `mutating`

Comment: "Doing such will mutate the object. a.x will be '5'. While `b.x` will be '3'. Swift doesn't want to allow this." This explanation is wrong, `a` and `b` can have different values of `x`. I do not know why you brought this into subject anyway. What Swift does not like is this part  `var isOn: Bool { x = 5 return true }`. It is about computed variable not `a` or `b` having different values of `x`. For the same reason we are not allowed to touch lazy from computed variable because it can change another variable inside computation closure. This is the explanation

Comment: @Farid lol. Not sure how that has been able to go unnoticed till you mentioned. Thank you pointing that out. Does it look ok now?

Comment: @mfaani Yes, looks perfect. Just one thing lazy is not an exception it is still part of the "A getter cannot mutate" error. Made an edit

Comment: @Farid The way I see it is: `var isOn: Bool { x = 5; return true }` doesn't allow it to compile. Why? Because you can't mutate upon getting. However `lazy var x : Double = 3.0; print(x)` will mutate (in other words _set_) the value of `x` upon getting its value. And it compiles fine. This though was an exception to the Swift architecture rule I mentioned. Can you rollback your edit?

Comment: This will not compile because lazy is mutating. `struct ContentView: View {
    lazy var x : Double = 3.0

    var body: some View {
       Text("\(x)") // ERROR
    }
}` Am I missing something on your reply?

Comment: @Farid. I believe you're missing.. What you're talking about is something **else**. Instead let's focus on this example: `struct Foo { lazy var x : Double = 3.0 } ; print(x)` (Nothing is SwiftUI). When you do `print(x)` are you mutating the `Foo` instance? You'd say yes. Next question: was the value of `x` set before doing `pinrt(x)`? You's day No. But didn't we say "Swift has an architecture that doesn't allow "getters to mutate an object"? How does this happen then? My answer: `lazy` is an exception. It allows a getter to set. Would you mind rolling back the edit if everything is ok?

Comment: @mfaani Yeap, I got it and rolled it back. I do not know if people will still be confused with that example or not. I would suggest we change the code for  **Lazy is mutating** to this `struct Device2 {
    
    var x = 3
    lazy var isOn: Bool = {
        x = 5
        return true
    }()
}

let a = Device2()
let b = a

print(a.isOn)`

Comment: @Farid I made another edit. I humbly prefer it the way it is now. Folks can read your comments here. or you if you like, maybe you can write another answer...